# Bootstrap Navigation bug with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am far from being a JS/jQuery expert and just found a bug on my site. After adding this piece of code to my slider:  my bootstrap navigation started to stop working. This is the code of the navigation:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script> $('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 3500 }) </script>
<div class="container">

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>



            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><br /></a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="dropdown ">
```

If I now press to open the navigation I can't close it again and also I can't open the dropdown menus of my navbar.

Comment: Try opening your browser tools to see if there are any JavaScript errors in there. If there are, add them to your question.

Comment: You should load your scripts under your content (just before closing body tag).